# Get information horizontal in Report Footer

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

I have a information like this in the details section

S. No Pro. Code Qty
    1.       A2509.       10
    2.       C9809.         5
    3.       D9809.         7

When I bring this field in the report footer,I am getting only the first field.

Is it possible to bring information like this in the report Footer?

A2509,C9809,D9809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with shared variables:

Create a formula like this and set it after details section:

- Shared StringVar Product; Product:= {Table1.YourField}; ""

On report footer put this:

- Shared StringVar Product;

Or you could create a sub-report:

- Set your field on details and supress all other.